# How can I add different pictures to a row of div's that share the same class?

Tags: html

I'd like to add different pictures and links to each one of these div's that I have. How would this be possible?

```
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: I think it is best to learn the very basics of html before attempting to code

Comment: I know advanced HTML but the basics are the things that get me every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Use the HTML <img> element to define an image.
```

Use the HTML src attribute to define the URL of the image.
Use the HTML alt attribute to define an alternate text for an image, if it cannot be displayed.
Use the HTML width and height attributes to define the size of the image.

```
<div class="box">
  <img src="pic1.jpg">
</div>

<div class="box">
   <img src="pic2.jpg">
</div>

<div class="box">
   <img src="pic3.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: I think you need to update this answer, it is very incomplete offers no explanation and not valid HTML

Comment: This was the answer I needed! Thank you!